# How to mark the selected option as selected?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am using ajax pagination where i am giving my users an opportunity to select record per page though provided option.The problem is every time the 1st option  remains as selected no matter which option i am selecting!How to solve this problem so that only the selected option remains as selected!

jquery+ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
changePagination('0');    
});


function changePagination(pageId){

     $(".flash").show();
     $(".flash").fadeIn(800).html
         ('Loading <img src="ajax-loader.gif" />');

     var dataString = {pageId: pageId, recordsPerPage: $('select[name="rp"] option:selected').html()};
           type: "POST",
           url: "page.php",
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
           success: function(result){
           $(".flash").hide();
           $("#pageData").html(result);
           }
      });
}
</script>
```

Option:

```
<select id="rp" name="rp" onChange=" changePagination();">
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="8">8</option>            
<option value="10">10</option>            
</select>
```

Comment: Provide the `console.log` output of `dataString`.

Answer (score 1):

You can select one of the options and give `selected` property on it.

```
// 'n' will be your index value for selecting and making one of the options stay selected.
$('#rp option').eq(n).attr('selected', true);
$('#rp option').eq(n).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

---

**FYI**

`.attr()` could not work properly in a certain jQuery version. If it happens to you, use `prop()` instead. Since `selected` is a property, not an attribute, using `prop()` would be semantically and synthetically right.

```
$('#rp option').eq(n).prop('selected', true);
$('#rp option').eq(n).prop('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the current value of the `select` form element, then this will do:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  changePagination('0');    
});

function changePagination(pageId){
  alert( $('select[name="rp"]').val() );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="rp" name="rp" onChange="changePagination();">
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="8">8</option>            
<option value="10">10</option>            
</select>
```

Comment: Actually i don't need the value just want to mark the associated option as selected !

Comment: I am trying to Dynamically mark an option as selected according  to the value of the selection but example from your provided link will always keep a particular  option as selected ignoring the current selection !!